# ag-Grid header styles not changing with CSS on component

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I'm using ag-Grid on my application and I have it ruining fine with the default theme (ag-theme-balham).

On one specific component I want to change the header background color, but when I add the CSS on my component.scss file nothing happens.

I added the ag-Grid css on my angular-cli.json file

```
  "styles": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss",
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css",
    "../node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-theme-balham.css",
    "styles.scss"
  ],
```

On component.scss file I have the following CSS

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-header {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

But nothing happens, and the color does not get applied to the header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the header-cell class instead

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-header-cell{
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

and if you have header-group then

```
.ag-theme-balham .ag-header-cell, .ag-theme-balham .ag-header-group-cell{
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try using ::ng-deep combinator

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep

```
::ng-deep .ag-theme-balham .ag-header {
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
}
```

If that does not work, put your css in the global stylesheet and check if the styles are overriden correctly

Answer (score 1):

A bit of an old question this is but to anyone coming into it now, this solution worked for me. The tags you need to write in are :

```
::ng-deep .ag-theme-balham .ag-header-cell-label{
/* your css here*/}
```

also the tag `!important` could also work

Answer (score 0):

Override `background-color` with `!important`.

That is:

```
:host {
    ::ng-deep { background-color: }
```